# Проблема русских символов в конфиге

Tags: java, minecraft

Я пытаюсь сделать плагин с конфигом, но каждый раз при написании русских символов в конфиг плагин выдаёт вопросительные знаки, но если ввести английские буквы то всё идёт нормально.

[image: Сами символы]

`String message_sender = plugin.getConfig().getString("pay.sender");` -> как я получал строку

```
File config = new File(getDataFolder() + File.separator + "config.yml");
        if(!config.exists()) {
            getLogger().info("Creating folder with database and config.yml");
            getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
            saveDefaultConfig();
        }
```

Как мне это иправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле оказалось нужно было в запускаторе прописать -Dfile.encode=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Написал бы комментарий, но пока не могу.

Чтобы это исправить надо совместить кодировки файла, в который вы пишите и читалки.
Т.е. при записи кодировка должна совпадать с файлом и при чтении кодировка так же должна совпадать с файлом.

Чтобы решить проблему, надо ответить на вопросы:

- В какой кодировке мы записываем в файл?
- В какой кодировке сам файл?
- В какой кодировке мы читаем из файла?

Если везде будет один и тот же ответ, то вопросики превратятся в нужные символы

ИМХО